# [SQL/PHP]Fieldname is a number and the type "int"

Tags: php, mysql, numbers, int, addition

I'm working on a website that will display different statistics for a gameserver and the problem is that the person who made the database named a lot of the fields after the weaponIDs to check how many kills someone got with that specific weapon (e.g. the field for AK47 is called "31").

Now, I want to display these in groups, with rocket launchers as one group and melee-weapons as one etc.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, (kills/deaths) as ratio, SEC_TO_TIME(timePlayed) as time, race1+race2+race3 as podiums, 35+36 as RPGs FROM `exm_player_sts_data` where accID = '$aid'") or die();
```

Here you can see that "race1+race2+race3 as podiums" will work well to display the number of times someone finished 1st, 2nd and 3rd as "podiums", but "35+36 as RPGs" will simply show it as 71.

How can I make it so it works like "fieldname+fieldname" instead of "numeric+numeric"?
I've tried with brackets, but that didn't want to work (I'm pretty new to this)

Comment: What SQL database are you using, I think the solution is implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using backquotes ?

```
`35` + `36`
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it. I assumed it was something as simple as that, but I couldn't find anything